# Error while try to start a web application teset with junit and spring

Tags: spring, testing, junit, spring-boot-test, applicationcontext

i'm trying to test a java spring web application and in particular i want to try some class that are injected in the application context. In order to do this i've found thate using the @SpringBootTest annotation i can obtain the application context. I wanted to create a simplet test to verify that i can actualy use it. I have a problem with the following test case:

```
@TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation.class)
@SpringBootTest
class ProvaContext {

@Autowired
protected ApplicationContext apt;

@Test
@Order(0)
void test1() {
    assertNotNull(apt);
}
@Test
@Order(0)
void test2() {
    apt=ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext();
    assertNotNull(apt);
}

}
```

When i start the server and try to run junit test with eclipse i get this error:

```
org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests
at  org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discoverEngineRoot(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:111)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discover(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:85)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discover(DefaultLauncher.java:92)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discover(DefaultLauncher.java:67)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.<init>(JUnit5TestReference.java:46)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit5TestLoader.java:76)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestLoader.createTest(JUnit5TestLoader.java:66)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit5TestLoader.java:53)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:513)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: ClassSelector [className = 'base.ProvaContext'] resolution failed
at org.junit.platform.launcher.listeners.discovery.AbortOnFailureLauncherDiscoveryListener.selectorProcessed(AbortOnFailureLauncherDiscoveryListener.java:39)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.resolveCompletely(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:102)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.run(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:82)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolver.resolve(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolver.java:113)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectorResolver.resolveSelectors(DiscoverySelectorResolver.java:45)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.JupiterTestEngine.discover(JupiterTestEngine.java:69)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discoverEngineRoot(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:103)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:724)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:531)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:355)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:286)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72)
at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:3521)
at java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:3510)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredAnnotation(Class.java:3458)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(AnnotationUtils.java:128)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.AnnotationUtils.findMetaAnnotation(AnnotationUtils.java:176)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(AnnotationUtils.java:134)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(AnnotationUtils.java:115)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.DisplayNameUtils.determineDisplayName(DisplayNameUtils.java:68)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.JupiterTestDescriptor.<init>(JupiterTestDescriptor.java:69)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.<init>(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:94)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.<init>(ClassTestDescriptor.java:51)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.ClassSelectorResolver.newClassTestDescriptor(ClassSelectorResolver.java:119)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.ClassSelectorResolver.lambda$resolve$0(ClassSelectorResolver.java:71)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution$DefaultContext.createAndAdd(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:246)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution$DefaultContext.addToParent(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:209)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.ClassSelectorResolver.resolve(ClassSelectorResolver.java:71)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.lambda$resolve$2(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:134)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(ArrayList.java:1361)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:486)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:531)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.resolve(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:185)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.resolve(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:125)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.resolveCompletely(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:91)
... 16 more
```

I can't figure out the problem. The pom.xml file has the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-engine -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Without the @SpringBootTest annotation the test run but the viriable apt is null. Thanks

Comment: Where's the rest of the `<dependency />` entries?